# Trying to run my Rust program on macOS has the error "use: command not found"

Tags: macos, rust

This is my code in Atom, with the Atom-Language-Rust package installed:

```
use std::{i8, i16, i32, i64, u8, u16, u32, u64, isize, usize, f32, 
f64};

use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This is what I'm inputting into the terminal:

```
rustc hello_world.rs -A warning
./hello_world.rs
```

This is the error message:

```
./hello_world.rs: line 1: use: command not found
./hello_world.rs: line 2: use: command not found
./hello_world.rs: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello_world.rs: line 4: `fn main() {'
```

What did I do wrong in code or in setup?

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to execute the source code file, not a compiled binary. The point of compilation is to take source code and produce an executable. You want

```
rustc hello_world.rs
./hello_world
```

---

Let's go into all the other issues:

1. Most importantly, you appear to be actively avoiding using the existing **amazing** and **free** resources for learning Rust. Specifically, I'd *strongly* recommend that you stop what you are doing and go read the first few chapters of [*The Rust Programming Language*, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/). How to invoke the compiler and execute code is covered there. Hint: Very few people execute `rustc` directly and all of them have very good reasons to do so.
2. The Rust compiler will tell you a world of useful hints. These are called *lints*. However, it appears that you are attempting to *disable the lints* via `-A warning`. Ignoring hints from the compiler is a very bad idea as a beginner.
3. `-A warning` isn't even *valid*. Trying to use it, I get the error

   > error: unknown lint: `warning`

   I'd be interested to know where you learned of this so we can attempt to correct the misinformation at the source.
4. You have imported *way* more things than you need. **None** of the lines imported via `use` are needed — the compiler tells you that when you read the warnings.

---

A little bit more exploration of the problem...

Somehow, you have saved your source code file and marked it as executable. When you attempt to execute it, the operating system and/or shell checks to see if it's a binary file. If it's not, it attempts to treat the file as a *shell script*. Shell scripts have a special line called the *shebang* (`#!`) at the beginning to tell which *interpreter* should be used. Since this file doesn't have that, it's assumed to be a shell script for the `/bin/sh` interpreter.

Thus, `/bin/sh` is handed your Rust code and tries to run it, line-by-line. That's what all the errors are - the shell complaining that each line it attempts isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: Spot on! And very helpful for those starting to learn the language.

Comment: @Stargateur - I don't have this problem. I don't think I can accept an answer to someone else's issue. I praised the poster for his comprehensive explanation. I think you need to take the [tour].

Comment: @Shepmaster, That solved my problem, thank you! I was initially using that book you linked, however, I was looking for an IDE and I didn't have any clear guidance on that so I searched for a comprehensive Rust tutorial for Mac on youtube, hoping to find something that starts from installation to which text editor to use, etc

Comment: @MichaelChow Now, I can say my speech. If this answer solve your problem, consider to accepting it, [tour].